# Push one array into another

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays as following.

```
var first = [['2','23','33'],['2','23','33'],['2','23','33']]

var second = ['value1','value2','value3']
```

Now i want to push second array into first like this.

```
var first = [['value1','value2','value3'],['2','23','33'],['2','23','33'],['2','23','33']]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use [**unshift**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift?v=control) to adds element to the beginning of an array

```
var first = [['2','23','33'],['2','23','33'],['2','23','33']]

var second = ['value1','value2','value3']
first.unshift(second)
```